# Changing ImageView of CollectionViewCell outside cellForItemAtIndexPath (and without reloadData)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view. On tap on any collection view cell, I am trying to upload/store images on Firebase and at the same time, change the background image of the cell with the uploaded image

I have the IBOutlet of UIImageView called `currentImage` in my CollectionViewCell class.

After I convert the image to base64String and upload the image, at this point, I want to manipulate the currentImage of the tapped cell. But (if it's possible) I'd prefer to update the cell image internally rather than uploading it and re-fetching it; and if I use collectionView.reloadData(), it will fetch it again.

---

I am getting the index of tapped cell. I thought something like this would work but it doesn't grab the cell's outlet from the Collection View..

```
 let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: tappedCell!, inSection: 0)
 collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) = image
```

..whereas, it  works in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as `cell.currentImage`.

---

Is there a way to achieve it outside `cellForItemAtIndexPath` or is the only way `collectionView.reloadData()`?

*PS. I have 5 images, not unlimited..*

Comment: why does `reloadData()` fetch it again? If you write your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` in a way that it checks whether there's an internal image (either in memory or on local disk) first, and if not fetches it, you get the same result. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Oh, doesn't it re-fetch it? I though it has to re-fetch everything if you do reloadData..

Comment: `reloadData()` will just force the `tableViewController` to cycle again through the rows and ask the dataSource for the data. It's up to how you implement your dataSource delegate whether or not something is fetched over the network.